# How to use jwt/interceptor in angular for login/register method

Tags: angular, authentication, jwt

I am creating a register and login method. I use an interceptor but it is error 401. I don't get the token to set the Header.

This is my code: https://stackblitz.com/github/ntgiang4991/jwt

File token.interceptor.ts:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log(request);
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    request = this.addToken(request, token)

    return next.handle(request);
  }

  private addToken(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: string){
    return request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'Authorization': `Token ${token}`,
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
      },
    })
  }
```

File auth.service.ts

```
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private jwt: JwtService
  ) { }

  login(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post('https://conduit.productionready.io/api/users/login', { email, password });
  }

  register(username: string, email: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<{ token: string }>('https://conduit.productionready.io/api/users', { username, email, password }).pipe(tap(res => {
      this.login(email, password)
    }))
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
  }

  public get loggedIn(): boolean {
    return localStorage.getItem('token') !== null;
  }
```

File register.component.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
        <div class="card rounded-0 mt-5">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="mb-0">Register</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form action="" class="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username">Username</label>
                        <input [(ngModel)]="registerUserData.username" name="username" type="text" required class="form-control rounded-0">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input [(ngModel)]="registerUserData.email" name="email" type="text" required class="form-control rounded-0">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input [(ngModel)]="registerUserData.password" name="password" type="password" required class="form-control rounded-0">
                    </div>
                    <button (click)="registerUser()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

File register.component.ts

```
 registerUser() {
    console.log(this.registerUserData.username, this.registerUserData.email, this.registerUserData.password);
    this._auth.register(this.registerUserData.username, this.registerUserData.email, this.registerUserData.password).subscribe(
      res => console.log(res),
      err => console.log(err)
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

After setting the headers to update the headers in real time you have init the headers that can be done by calling `headers.keys()`

Here is the updated addToken Method :

```
private addToken(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: string){
    const newReq = request.clone({
       setHeaders: {
          'Authorization': `Token ${token}`,
          'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
       },
    })
    newReq.headers.keys();
    return newReq;  
}
```

Comment: It had got the token but the value of the token is "null". Can you help me? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think its a bearer token.

```
    export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(public auth: AuthService) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
        const myRequest =  request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    });
        return next.handle(myRequest);
    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

Comment: My token is null. Do you know why? Thank you!

Comment: Does you have token present in your Browser localStorage?, If yes can you log the token in interceptor?

Comment: My token log is "null". I don't know to get the token and then save it to local storage?

Comment: most cases after login, we save the token given by into localStorage by localStorage.setItem('token', token value) once its set, it will be visible in developer tools->application->localStorage->token, only when its present u can get the token by localStorage.getToken.

Comment: This is the first login, how do I get the token when the login is false?

Comment: generally, only on successfully login, we will get token from API, then we will store it in localstorage

Comment: on successfull login add Token to local storage, then u will be able to add it in interceptor

Comment: After successful login set the token in local storage.

Answer (score 0):

try this intercep :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpResponse,
  HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';

import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(public auth: AuthService) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    console.log(request);
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
         if (token) {
          let clonedReq = this.addToken(request, token);
          return next.handle(clonedReq).pipe(
          map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
              if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                console.log('event-body-->>>', event.body);
              }
              return event;
          }),
          catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
              console.log('error',error);
              return throwError(error.error);
          }));
      } else {
        return next.handle(request);
      }
  }

     private addToken(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: any) {
  if (token) {
      let clone: HttpRequest<any>;
      clone = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
              'Authorization': `Token ${token}`,
              'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            }
        });
      return clone;
    }
  return request;
}
}
```